# Get body of response in Superoak

Tags: integration-testing, deno

I'm doing integration testing on Deno with Superoak and my application has one time password, for test a feature I need to know the one time password but for it I need its secret, which is informed on the body of the response of a POST.

I want to know how to get the response of this POST on Superoak.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it mocking the class that create the one time password and added to it a fixed secret, then I won't need to get the body of the response on Superoak.